Is it possible to use ProtectedLocalStorage without regular .NET Core?
Seems like an obvious upgrade from regular localstorage, but I've only seen it used with Blazor.
I'm using ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC.
Should I just put this in my program.cs?
builder.Services.AddScoped<ProtectedLocalStorage>();



It is not possible to use ProtectedLocalStorage in an MVC project. It can only be used in Blazor server project.


Protected Browser Storage relies on ASP.NET Core Data Protection and
is only supported for server-side Blazor apps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=server#aspnet-core-protected-browser-storage

You could use a cookie to persist the state in an MVC project, a minimal example here:


set cookie:
Httpcontext.Response.Cookies.Append("key", "value", new CookieOptions(){......})

read cookie:
HttpContext.Request.Cookies["key"]


